# I can't do a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, mongodb

I have this variable: `Física` in mongoDB and I have a model whose attribute `name` is `Educación Física`.

I would make a regular expression that passing the variable `Física` NOT return me `Educación Física` but if the database had a model whose name was `fisica` or `FisiCa` or something, I give it back YES.

I am using `nodeJS`, `mongoDB`, `Javascript`...

Sorry about my english and thank you so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The things you need for that are:

1. *Anchors*: `^` means "beginning of input" and `$` means "end of input"
2. *Case insensitivity*: The `i` flag means "ignore whether things are capitalized or not"

So:

```
var rex = /^fisica$/i;
//         ^      ^ ^
//         |      | +------ i flag (ignore case)
//         +------+-------- anchors
```

Example:

```
if (rex.test(someString)) {
    // It matches...
}
```

Re your comment below:

> how I can put fisica like variable? because fisica is an example, it is a variable sends from frontend to backend

For that, you'd need the regular expression constructor, `RegExp`:

```
var rex = new RegExp("^" + yourVariable + "$", "i");
```

If there are any characters in the value in `yourVariable` that are special in regular expressions, they need to be escaped with a backslash. [This question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript) cover escaping a regular expression. So in that case:

```
var rex = new RegExp("^" + someQuotingFunction(yourVariable) + "$", "i");
```

Answer (score 1):

In mongoDB you can use [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) in a query with options like following:

```
db.collection.find({name:{$regex:/^fisica/, $options:'i'}})
```